# Join child table when using joined inheritance table [Predicates]

Tags: jpa-2.0, predicate

I have parent:child inheritance model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Parent {
  ...
  id
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
public class Child extends Parent {
   ... 
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<Foo> foos = new HashSet<>();
}
```

How can I join those two tables using the `Predicates`? Precondition being that the root is `Root<Parent>`. This is already done by default by the JPA but I require a join object access between those two to further join the `Foo` list.

```
CriteriaQuery<Parent> q = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);
Root<Parent> r = q.from(Parent.class);

Join<Parent, Child> cJoin = r.join("???", JoinType.LEFT);  <-- ERROR
cJoin.on(cb.equal(r.get("id"), cJoin.get("id")));

Join<Child, Foo> fJoin = cJoin.join("foos", JoinType.LEFT);
fJoin.on(cb.equal(r.get("id"), cJoin.get("id")));
```

I don't know how to express the child table name, see the `"???"` in the code example.
This produces `Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [???]`. I have tried writting `child`, `Child` to no avail.

Or is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

The [JPA CriteriaQuery Join - how to join on a subelement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867822/jpa-criteriaquery-join-how-to-join-on-a-subelement) solution isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a subquery:

```
CriteriaQuery<Parent> q = cb.createQuery(Parent.class);
Root<Parent> r = q.from(Parent.class);

Subquery<Long> childSubQuery = q.subquery(Long.class);
Root<Child> childRoot = childSubQuery.from(Child.class);
Join<Child, Foo> fJoin = childRoot.join("foos", JoinType.LEFT);
fJoin.on(cb.equal(childRoot.get("id"), fJoin.get("id")));
childSubQuery.select(childRoot.get("id"));
childSubQuery.where(cb.equal(fJoin.get("condition"), conditionValue));

q.where(cb.equal(r.get("id"), childSubQuery));
```

Note: Obviously if you have a chance, use the composition as suggested in the mentioned link.